# How exactly does the Gyrocopters Flak Cannon work?

Tags: dota

I recently used the Gyrocopter for the first time and I must say, he was an extremely fun play.

His Flak Cannon ability seemed to work great for farming, allowing my basic attacks to target everything around me in an 800 range aoe. (works nice in team fights too)

I soon noticed however, that if I activated my Rocket Barrage skill with Flak Cannon up, the Rockets seemed to ALSO target everything in the 800 aoe. This leads to my question, what exactly does the Flak Cannon apply to? The two guides sported at playdota.com don't specify, so I'm asking here.

Does Flak Cannon apply only to my basic attack? (was I wrong with my impression that it upgrades Rocket Barrage as well?) Or does it apply to other skills, if so which ones and how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several games later has brought me to the educated conclusion that I was mistaken. Apparently Flak Cannon's visual effect is MISSILES striking everything within the previously mentioned aoe of 800. This gave me the false impression that it was effecting my Missile Barrage skill because I thought the missiles I saw hitting so far out were from the Barrage skill but in-fact were from the Flak Cannon skill.

**Flak Cannon only effects Gyrocopters Basic Attack**

Comment: furthermore a strategic hint: atacking creeps while using flak will give your hero 800 atk range harass while farming safely. this often is underrated by many players.